# How to show() and hide() blocks of list items using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, content-management-system, html-lists

I have a site that dynamically produces list items as follows:

```
<li class="comment even thread-odd thread-alt depth-1" id="li-comment-10">...</li>
<li class="comment odd alt thread-even depth-1" id="li-comment-17">...</li>
<li class="comment even thread-odd thread-alt depth-1" id="li-comment-20">...</li>
<li class="comment byuser comment-author-not-used-2 odd alt depth-2" id="li-comment-21">
...</li>
```

There are currently over 40 of these items that follow the pattern above.

I want to use jQuery to show/hide the list items in blocks of 5. I know how to code the jQuery for toggling but what I can't figure out is how to count and tag the blocks of 5 for showing and hiding.

The dilemma is that these `<li>`'s are auto generated in a CMS and dynamically rendered on the page. So I want to use JavaScript/jQuery to come in after the page is rendered and identify and somehow tag blocks of 5 list items.

Is that do-able?

Hope this makes some sense.

Comment: Do you mean that there are over 40 `ul` elements?

Comment: No, over 40 `<li></li>` element containers @guest271314

Comment: What do mean by `<li></li>` containers? Is requirement to show only 5 `li` elements within `ul` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `:lt()` selector with parameter `5`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul li:lt(5)").show()
})
```

```css
ul li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<ul>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Excellent solution @guest271314. This does exactly what I need it too. Thank you very, very much for helping!!

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over them with some math using the jQuery `:eq()` selector.  For example, you can get the 2nd `<li>` with `$("li:eq(1)")`.

Comment: Cool and intriguing. I'll start working on that @Quinto. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for helping @Quinto. The answer from (at)guest271314 ends up working exactly as I need. So i selected that one as the answer. But I greatly appreciate your help on this!